# Реализация барабана

Tags: javascript, php, svg

Хочу переделать ролл рулетки(сделать еёё барабаном)
 Код самого барабана я реализовал:

```
  <?php
            $prizes = $db->query("SELECT * FROM priz WHERE caseid='$caseid'")->fetchAll();
            $count = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM priz WHERE case='$case'")->fetch()[0];
            $margin = -10;
          for ($i=0; $i < 36; $i++) {
              $id= mt_rand(0,$count-1);
              $margin = $margin + 10;
               ?>
 <div class="fortune-item" style="transform: rotate(<?=$margin?>deg);">
                        <img src="<?=$priz[$id]['img']?>">
                      </div>
          <?php  } ?>
```

а вот с js проблемы, как мне переписать js под вращение по кругу до нужного элемента:

```
  $("#roul").append(itm);
        var container = $('#roul');
        var scrollTo = $(".item[data-num='"+unx+"']");
        container.animate({scrollLeft: scrollTo.offset().left - container.offset().left + container.scrollLeft()-470+rand(1,60)},{duration: 10000,easing: 'swing',complete: function() {
```

вот так выглядит барабан

[image: барабан]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94985/discussion-on-question-by-drowdev--).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SVG` + `transform: rotate`

```js
let items = [0,32,15,19,4,21,2,25,17,34,6,27,13,36,11,30,8,23,10,5,24,16,33,1,20,14,31,9,22,18,29,7,28,12,35,3,26];        
let r1 = 45, r2 = 35, sectors = "", texts = "", spins = 0;
with (Math) for (var i = 0; i <= items.length; i++) {
  let a = 2*PI/items.length*i, x = cos(a), y = sin(a); 
  if (i > 0) 
    sectors += `L${x*r2},${y*r2}L${x*r1},${y*r1}Z"></path>`
  if (i < items.length) {
    sectors += `<path fill="${i?i%2?'red':'black':'green'}" d="M${x*r1},${y*r1}L${x*r2},${y*r2}`;
    a += PI/items.length, x = cos(a), y = sin(a), r3 = (r1 + r2)/2 - 0.5;
    texts += `<text id="${a}" x="${x*r3}" y="${y*r3}" transform="rotate(${a/PI*180+90} ${x*r3} ${y*r3})">${items[i]}</text>`
  }
}
roulette.innerHTML = sectors + texts;

window.onclick = () => {
  spins += 2;
  let c = Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length);
  val.innerHTML = 'rolling to ' + c;
  let cell = roulette.querySelectorAll('text')[items.indexOf(c)];
  roulette.setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${spins*360-cell.id/Math.PI*180-90})`)
  roulette.timeout && clearTimeout(roulette.timeout);
  roulette.timeout = setTimeout(() => val.innerHTML = 'click to rotate', 1e4)
}
```

```css
text {
  fill:white;
  font-size:5px;
  dominant-baseline: middle;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

text#val {
  fill:black;
}

body {
  user-select:none;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0;
}

g {
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition: 10s;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="-50 -50 100 100" height="100vh">
<text id="val">click to rotate</text>
<g id="roulette"></g>
<path d="M0,-34.5L-2,-30L2,-30Z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Понимаю, что это не нужно ТС, но: если вы позволяете продлить время вращения следующим кликом - нужно также перезапускать timeout для очистки.

Comment: @vp_arth справедливо, добавил одну строчку